# converting datetime format to time with only hour and minute

Tags: datetime, time, type-conversion

I have values in datetime format. ex: 2012-10-17 00:05:00.000 
I casted them into time format ex: 00:05:00.000 but it is still too long for me. I just want hour and minute part of that time. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var dateTime = new DateTime(2012, 10, 17, 0, 5, 0, 0);
var hoursAndMinutes = dateTime.ToShortTimeString();
```